# Discord bot isn't changing it's nickname using client.user.edit

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord.py

I am using the following python code and `discord.py` to make a discord bot with an instance of `discord.Client`. I want the bot to be able to change its avatar and nickname on the guilds to match that of the user that sent the most recent message, in an `on_message(message:discord.Message)` function. If you know about the Not Quite Nitro bot, I want to do something similar to that(only in terms of changing the look of the bot to match a guild Member). The avatar change worked, at least the first time. Then, it threw the following exception most of the following times I tried to test it:

```py
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In avatar: You are changing your avatar too fast. Try again later.
```

I assume there is some sort of cooldown on avatar changing. Is there a way to circumvent that?

In addition, the nickname has never changed successfully. I have given the bot a nickname on the guild so that there is something to change, in case that would fix it. Here is  the code:
**All inconsistent indents are a result of stackoverflow and copying and pasting, they are not in the actual code**

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author==client.user:
        return
    #some irrelevant code removed here
        async with message.channel.typing():
            #the code omitted here is irrelevant and worked
            #the below code is the problematic portion
                    try:
                        await message.delete()
                        asset = message.author.avatar_url_as()
                        avatarBytes = await asset.read()
                        await client.user.edit(nick=message.author.display_name)
                        try:
                          await client.user.edit(avatar=avatarBytes)
                        except discord.errors.HTTPException:
                          #this error is the avatar changing too fast error
                          pass
                    await message.channel.send(content=message.content,files=fileList)
                except discord.errors.HTTPException:
                    await message.channel.send("Too many images to send")
                    #for reference, this except block only triggers when it would have to send more than 10 files at once
```

the bot is authorized to delete messages and manage nicknames. What is going on here?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem 1 (patching nickname of the bot)

You can't edit the bot's nickname like this, as you can see in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.edit). To edit the bot's nickname in a guild you have to do:

```
await message.guild.me.edit(nick=message.author.display_name)
```

[me](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.me) is the instance of `discord.Member` of your bot in a guild.

#### Problem 2 (patching the avatar of your bot)

Secondly, according to discord.py, the ratelimit for patching the bot's account is 2/3600s (`PATCH Username` is the word used there). So, this part of your bot can be used to do want you want to do.

#### Other solution (webhooks)

But I have a solution to do what you want and I think that NQN is using it : [webhooks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#webhook-support).
You can create a webhook and use it to send a message with the avatar and the username you want (defined on every message sent with the webhook). But the appearance of your bot itself will not change, it will only be the avatars and the names of the webhooks used that will change.

#### References for the solution

[create a webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_webhook)

[get a webhook from an url](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.from_url)

[send a message with a webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.send)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me somewhat. However, now I have a new problem. once it reads the bytes of the Asset, it skips everything else, not editing the webhook user, deleting the message, or sending a copy of the message. `not webhook==None` in this case. ```asset = message.author.avatar_url_as()
                avatarBytes = await asset.read()
                await webhook.edit(name=message.author.display_name, avatar=avatarBytes)
                await webhook.send(message.content, files=fileList)

                await message.delete()

```

Comment: I was thinking it might be a permission error. I am waiting for the server founder to give it the admin role, I authorized it with admin permissions to be safe, but in my past experience on this particular server at least it seems to also need the admin role

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much! I gave my bot a bunch more permissions and made all the webhooks, and it works now